# Does spark auto spill to disk?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a cluster that is 10 nodes with each having 244GB memory and 1TB memory.

If I have a data set that is 500GBx10 does spark auto default to disk spill or do I have to call `persist` and default storage level to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` ?

Answer (score 0):

`cache` will cache the data into memory and once memory is full it will spill to disk. The default storage level is `MEMORY_AND_DISK`. If you want any other option, you can provide that option using `persist` method with desired option to store the results.

`persist` has different options, but `cache` is like persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK option.

Below link gives more information on it.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence